# Hibernate Entities Definition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am new to hibernate. I am designing an application in spring boot with JPA Hibernate.

I have database schema as :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `restaurants` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `rest_offer_map` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I guess schema is clear. Now It could be the case that an restaurant exists without any offer. How do I create entities so that I could achieve left join.
Also there is a column named status in every table, it needs to be taken care of (especially in left join as in that case status will be a join condition)

The o/p I want is list of all restaurants with the offers(in any), so left join is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the Restaurant entity as the owning side of the relationship as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurants")
public class Restaurant implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="rest_offer_map",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="rest_id", referencedColumnName="id"),              inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="offer_id",referencedColumnName="id"))
private Collection<Offer> offers;
        .....

}
```

And the Offer entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name"offers")
public class Offer implements Serializable{
     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private Long id;
     ManyToMany(mappedBy="offers")
     private Collection<Restaurant> restaurants;
......
}
```

Comment: referencedColumnName are from tables restaurants or from rest_order_mapping?

Comment: **referencedColumnName** are from **restaurant** and **offers** tables.The **rest_order_mapping** table is a join table and holds references **foreign_keys** to restaurants and offers tables.Hence **id** column in **restaurants** table and **id** column on **offers** table are the `referencedColumnName`s with respect to the **rest_order_mapping** table'.

Comment: 100 likes to answer. !! CHeers.....!!... One  more question. When I am adding ManyToMany(mappedBy="offers")
     private Collection<Restaurant> restaurants; this, it is giving Infinite Loop when I am getting the rest objects. as Offers Object is inside Rest Object and rest Object is inside Offers. What am i missing

Comment: This is bidirectional relationship.restaurants has its collections of offers and each offer has a collection of restaurants its being offered at.You need to mark **restaurants** getter on the **Offer** entity with @XmlTransient

Comment: @Transient works, but this is the case when I am trying to print all restaurants, so I am getting this o/p, {"id":2,"name":"Rest 2","offer":[{"id":1,"detail":"Offer 1","restaurants":null}]}, But what I want to print offers entity, meaning lets say I have requirement where I have to print an specific order object with filled restaurant. since it is transient, it will not persist.?

Comment: Do not mark **restaurants** as **@Transient** but rather **@XmlTransient.This is because **Transient** fields are not managed will be ignored by JPA hence you get null.**@XmlTranient** will ignore this filed during serialization which is where the infinite loop is originating from.This way it will still have values in memory.

Comment: Nops.  !!! with @XmlTransient, I am getting Infinite Loop. FYI, I am using RestController and thus my o/p is in JSON nd not XML. like this...  {"id":2,"name":"Rest 2","offer":[{"id":1,"detail":"Offer 1","restaurants":[{"id":2,"name":"Rest 2","offer":[{"id":1,"detail":"Offer 1","restaurants":[{"id":2,"name":"Rest 2","offer":[{"id":1,"detail":"Offer 1","restaurants":[{"id":2,"name":"Rest 2","offer":[{"id":1,"detail":"Offer 1","restaurants":[{"id":2,"name":"Rest 2","o.. How about @JsonIgnore? Is it the same thing? Also,if I use this, then same ques, if want to print offers with rest. the how?